# Setting CALayer frame doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, calayer, nsview

I'm creating a version of the game 2048 at the moment and I'm trying to draw the background of one of the tiles. So I have an NSView with the size of 100 x 100, and I want this views layer background colour to be 90 x 90.

This is my code:

```
    // Set view as wanting layer
    self.wantsLayer = YES;

    // Create layer for view
    self.layer.backgroundColor = [self backgroundColor:n].CGColor;
    self.layer.frame = CGRectInset(self.frame, 20, 20);
```

The background colour goes through fine, but the frame doesn't change at all. The frame is the same frame as the parent NSView.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at using `borderColor` and `borderWidth`?

Comment: The view and its layer have the same size. I think you are looking for a sublayer instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can set position of your layer.

```
  // Set view as wanting layer
    self.wantsLayer = YES;

    // Create layer for view
    self.layer.backgroundColor = [self backgroundColor:n].CGColor;
    self.layer.position = CGPointMake(x, y);
```

With Animation

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:2.0];
self.layer.position = CGPointMake(x, y);
[CATransaction commit];
```

Without Animation

```
   [CATransaction begin]; 
   [CATransaction setValue: (id) kCFBooleanTrue forKey: kCATransactionDisableActions];
   //self.layer.position = CGPointMake(x, y);
   self.layer.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 90, 90);//set frame as per your requirement
   [CATransaction commit];
```

Hope it helps you.....

Comment: But it's not the position I want to set, it's the size. The NSView is 100x100 and I want its layer to be 90x90.

Comment: set View over layer and then give color to view.